# Have UIimageView width of custom TableViewCell be 1/3 of cell width, and height of cell = image aspect ratio

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm new to iOS programming, and I'm mainly been using the interface builder to adjust cell layouts. 
Currently I have a custom TableView cell with an ImageView and Label.

I would like to:

1) Have the ImageView Width = 1/3 size of cell ( It doesn't seem like I can do this via storyboard)

2) Have the cell height dynamically adjust as the aspect ratio of image is maintained. I've already added constraints for the UIImageView to equal cell height.

I searched StackOverflow but some of the answers got really complicated, so I couldn't really understand how to fit it to my case. 
I played around with constraints, but it seems I have to do this programmatically?

Here is what I currently have for cell methods:

```
extension FirstTableViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataCells.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let folderCell = dataCells[indexPath.row]
        print(folderCell)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FirstTableViewCell
        cell.setCell(cell:folderCell)
        return cell
```

Here is my cell class:

```
class FirstTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: ScaledHeightImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var FolderLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        //print(FolderLabel)


    }
    func setCell (cell : FolderCell){
        self.ImageView.image = cell.image
        self.FolderLabel.text = cell.label
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it from storyboard by adding equal width with superview, then change it's Multiplier to be 0.3[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah, Thank you =).

Comment: Sorry, to bother you but how did you get the  equal Width to Superview?  
Do you click both the view and imageView and select "equal widths"? 
Thank you.

Comment: Any time, Ctrl + drag from over image view to contentView "cell background"

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean just "contentView"?  I see "contentView" but I'm not sure I don't see  "cell background."

Comment: Thank you. Sorry to bother you again. I added the constraints as you suggested, but if I make a the multiplier .5,  some images don't seem to take up half the cell, while others take up more than half. I have aspect fit checked. It seems I still need to change the height of the cell dynamically  so that it can maintain the aspect ratio while only taking up half the cell. How would I go about doing this? Thank you.